# How do i add a page 1, 2, 3 ,4 next button at the bottom of my website

Tags: node.js, express

I am developing a website from where people can download files. I will upload files to the website which will show up at the home page. Now I want to make only the first 10 files to show on the home page . Rest of the files will be shown in the next page. I mean Only ten files will appear on a single page. Then you have to click 'next' button to view more files. I am developing the website with nodejs express js . Can you tell me how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is known as `pagination`, you need to handle on both front and backend. it is a detail process so i will share some links for reference

[Backend Pagination with node express mongodb mongoose and EJS](https://itnext.io/back-end-pagination-with-nodejs-expressjs-mongodb-mongoose-ejs-3566994356e0)

[Simple Pagination with Node.js, Express, and Mongoose](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/simple-pagination-with-node-js-mongoose-and-express-4942af479ab2)

[Server Side Pagination Using Node and Mongo](https://codeforgeek.com/server-side-pagination-using-node-and-mongo/)